# Извлечение строки из выборки в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Есть sql запрос и получение результатов sql запроса

```html
<?php
        $hostname="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbname="dbcall";

        $userslistconn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($userslistconn === false) {
            die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } 
        else {
            $userslistresult = mysqli_query( $userslistconn, "SELECT * FROM `users`" );
                if($userslistresult) {
                    $tableuserscontent='';
                    while($dbrowuser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userslistresult)){
                        $sqlExtractNameOperator = 'SELECT name FROM operators WHERE operators.id='.$dbrowuser['operator'];
                        $nameOperatorsListResult = mysqli_query( $userslistconn, $sqlExtractNameOperator );
                        if ($nameOperatorsListResult) {
                            while($dbrowoperatorinstance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nameOperatorsListResult)){
                                // echo '<option value=selectid'.$dbrowselectoperator['id'].'>'.$dbrowselectoperator['name'].'</option>';
                                $operatornameforuser=$dbrowoperatorinstance['name'];
                            }
                        }
                        $tableuserscontent .= '<tr class=user'.$dbrowuser['id'].'><td>'.$dbrowuser['name'].'</td><td>'.$dbrowuser['phonenumber'].'</td><td>'.$operatornameforuser.'</td></tr>';

                    }
                    echo $tableuserscontent;
            }
        }           
?>
```

Знаю по базе данных, что запрос вернет одну строчку. Каким образом из переменной `$nameOperatorsListResult` можно извлечь одну строку (приведите все варианты)?

Comment: ваша задача вообще без вложенного запроса в цикле решается. к запросу юзеров приджойните нужное сразу

Comment: Закрою, пожалуй, дублем, а в комментарии так и быть, открою автору секрет, что  у него в коде уже написано получение одной строки, `$dbrowoperatorinstance = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nameOperatorsListResult)`, только зачем-то обёрнутое в while, которое хотя конечно и не имеет смысла, но и вреда не несёт. А по-хорошему, как сказал @teran, должно быть `SELECT u.*, o.name as operator_name FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN operators AS o ON o.id=u.operator` в первом же цикле